# two cards are drawn without replacement from an ordinary​ deck

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

Two cards are drawn without replacement from an ordinary​ deck, find the probability that the second is not a queen​, given that the first is a queen.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! To ask a good question, please include what you have tried.

Comment: What are your thoughts? If you show what you worked out so far and explain how you got stuck, it could allow for a more useful answer.

Comment: Can you answer the question if the deck contains four cards, two of which are queens? That should get you started.

Comment: Please add what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it yourself.  There are 51 cards remaining and 3 queens.  If the cards are strictly random the probability of a queen is 3/51=1/17, so the probability of not a queen is 16/17.

Comment: iam trying to solve ...and your answer 3/51 is incorrect

Comment: The OP is trying to find the probability that the second card is NOT a queen. This is the probability that the second card is a queen.

Comment: thanks brothers >>>the correct answer is 16/17

Comment: Sorry - I misread the question.  The answer is now correct.